# Photos: imported AVI file from old camera has wrong date taken (day of import), but all metadata seems to be correct

Tags: photos.app, import

I'm trying to import all my photo library to Photos.app. I have several videos, which were taken in 2007 in AVI format on old digital camera. And that videos after imported appears in Photos.app like it was taken today (date of import). All metadata seems to be correct

This is output of `GetFileInfo`:

```
type: "\0\0\0\0"
creator: "\0\0\0\0"
attributes: avbstclinmedz
created: 08/20/2007 12:10:50
modified: 08/20/2007 12:10:50
```

This is output of `stat`:

```
872415234 3516139 -rwxrwxrwx 1 strate staff 0 6937758 "Aug 20 12:10:50 2007" "Aug 20 12:10:50 2007" "Aug 20 12:10:50 2007" "Aug 20 12:10:50 2007" 4096 13552 0 P8200030.AVI
```

And this is output of `exiftool`

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 11.85
File Name                       : P8200030.AVI
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 6.6 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2007:08:20 12:10:50+04:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2007:08:20 12:10:50+04:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2007:08:20 12:10:50+04:00
File Permissions                : rwxrwxrwx
File Type                       : AVI
File Type Extension             : avi
MIME Type                       : video/x-msvideo
Frame Rate                      : 15
Max Data Rate                   : 488.3 kB/s
Frame Count                     : 308
Stream Count                    : 1
Stream Type                     : Video
Video Codec                     : mjpg
Video Frame Rate                : 15
Video Frame Count               : 308
Quality                         : 10000
Sample Size                     : Variable
BMP Version                     : Windows V3
Image Width                     : 320
Image Height                    : 240
Planes                          : 1
Bit Depth                       : 24
Compression                     : MJPG
Image Length                    : 230400
Pixels Per Meter X              : 0
Pixels Per Meter Y              : 0
Num Colors                      : Use BitDepth
Num Important Colors            : All
Date/Time Original              : 2007:08:20 11:10:29
Software                        : OLYMPUS FE210/X775
Make                            : OLYMPUS DIGITAL CAMERA
Camera Model Name               : FE210,X775
F Number                        : 3.1
Date Time 1                     : Mon Aug 20 11:10:29 2007
Date Time 2                     : Mon Aug 20 11:10:29 2007
Thumbnail Width                 : 160
Thumbnail Height                : 120
Thumbnail Length                : 7410
Thumbnail Image                 : (Binary data 7410 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Aperture                        : 3.1
Image Size                      : 320x240
Megapixels                      : 0.077
Duration                        : 20.53 s
```

Seems that all metadata is are set to valid date, but it does not help. How can I fix it?